# Converting propositional logic formula to CNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I have been trying to do this all day but I am not getting anywhere with it, could anyone help me?

My formula is

```
r → (p ↔ ¬q)
```

And I want to convert it into CNF

When I do it, I get this answer, which does not seem correct:

```
(Q ∨ P ∨ ¬R) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ ¬R)
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I do it, I get this answer, which does not seem correct:
>
> > (Q ∨ P ∨ ¬R) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ ¬R)

That *is* correct.

Suppose $(Q ∨ P ∨ ¬R) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q ∨ ¬R)$ and assume $R$.  The assumption and supposition can both be satisfied when $P$ and $\lnot Q$, or when $\lnot P$ and $Q$ are satisfied: thus $R\to(P\leftrightarrow\lnot Q)$

Suppose $R\to(P\leftrightarrow\lnot Q)$.  This is satisfied when $R$ is falsified or $P\leftrightarrow\lnot Q$ is satisfied.  The later is satisfied at least one from $P,Q$ is satisfied *and* at least one is falsified.   This: $(\lnot R\lor P\lor Q)\land(\lnot R\lor\lnot P\lor\lnot Q).$